# Authorization to compare a claim with the current request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I can't find a simple way to do something that should be quite common.

I have Razor Pages and I want to add some authorization logic to ensure that a request

```
https://localhost:5001/admin/subscriptions/123`
```

where the `123` is any Guid is the `{subscriptionId}`.

I'm using a cookie based authentication, so I should have a claim `Name` or similar with a specific subscriptionId such as `124` for the current request.

I want to handle these subscription, so that it forbids access when the `subscriptionId` in the URL doesn't match a specific claim.

It's embarrassing but I don't know how to do it with AspNet Core 3.1 and Razor pages.

It simply doesn't seem to be design for these kind of scenarios. The examples I find consider that we know beforehand what the claims should be. For example in Microsoft official documentation it shows how an "age" claim can be compared to a minimum age of hardcoded magic int `21`.

What If both values are request-dependant?

When I add

```
services
                .AddAuthorization(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.AddPolicy(
                            "SameSubscriptionIdPolicy",
                            policy =>
                                policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                                {
                                    var claims = context.User.Claims;
                                    var subscriptionId = context.User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
                                    // how can I access here the Request and do the comparison?
                                }));
                    });
```

If I access the context, I see the URL parametrized, not the real value with the request.
I see `admin/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}` instead a specific value such as `admin/subscriptions/124`

**How can I access the URL query?** so that I can compare it with a claim value?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I read somewhere something [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#accessing-mvc-request-context-in-handlers) about casting like this:

```
context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext
```

That does not work. Resource is a `AuthorizationHandlerContext`

Also I've tried the following

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(
        options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "SameSubscriptionIdPolicy",
                policy =>
                    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    {
                        var claims = context.User.Claims;
                        var subscriptionId = context.User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
                        var accessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
                        var url = accessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
                        return false;
                    }));
        });
```

but `HttpContext` **is null**. Maybe by the time the policy starts, there is no request yet?

Answer (score 2):

It took a while but I managed to get it working for DotNetCore 3.1+.

It turns out I needed to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` service, so for that I decided not to use the inline policy func implementation and add all the pieces.
First an `IAuthorizationRequirement`

```
public class SubscriptionRequirement
    : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string ClaimName { get; }

    public SubscriptionRequirement(string claimName)
    {
        ClaimName = claimName;
    }
}
```

Not to leave an empty class I decided to pass it the claim name I'm looking for, so that it's a bit more generic.

then the `AuthorizationHandler` capable of accessing Claims (from cookie or whatever) and the http request.

```
public class SubscriptionRequirementHandler
    : AuthorizationHandler<SubscriptionRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SubscriptionRequirementHandler(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        SubscriptionRequirement subscriptionRequirement)
    {
        var claims = context.User.Claims;
        var subscriptionId = 
            context
                .User
                .FindFirst(x => x.Type == subscriptionRequirement.ClaimName)
                .Value;

        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var subscriptionIdInUrl = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["subscriptionId"];
        if (subscriptionIdInUrl != null)
        {
            var isAuthorized = subscriptionId == subscriptionIdInUrl.ToString();
            if (isAuthorized)
            {
                context.Succeed(subscriptionRequirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        context.Fail();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

To add this policy:

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(
        options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "SameSubscriptionIdPolicy",
                policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new SubscriptionRequirement(ClaimTypes.Name)));
        });
```

I can also (optionally for Razor Pages) specify that I want to apply this policy to all pages within a specific folder

```
services
    .AddRazorPages(
        options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/admin", "SameSubscriptionIdPolicy");
            options.Conventions.Add(new PageRouteTransformerConvention(new LowerCaseRoutes()));
        });
```

and finally, very importantly, register the handler and the http

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SubscriptionRequirementHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

---

**UPDATE 2020/06/18:**
As per Kirk's comment, a nicer way to register the `HttpContextAccessor` is to do so as a singleton using the already available extension instead.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: Don't register `IHttpContextAccessor` as _transient_. Use `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`, which registers it as a _singleton_. You may not even need to register it at all, since a few of the ASP.NET Core features register it automatically.

Comment: Good advice! I needed to register it, it was failing to resolve.